# Is it possible to modify ctrl-o behaviour in VIM?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using `minibufexplorer` plugin with VIM that displays buffers atop of my window. Default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (jump back using jumplist) opens files in separate buffers, so after a number of jumps displayed buffer count grows very large. Is it possible to modify <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> behaviour so it will open new buffer and close previous one? I have tried to program it with vimscript, but did not found any API to interact with jumplist. And if i replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> with my own function i don't know how to call the original implementation to do actual jump :(. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:normal!` to call the original implementation, like this:

```
function s:CtrlO(count1)
    let buf=bufnr('%')
    execute 'normal!' a:count1 "\<C-o>"
    if bufnr('%')!=buf
        execute 'bwipeout' buf
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <C-o> :<C-u>call <SID>CtrlO(v:count1)<CR>
```